# append an element to an array and resize an array

Tags: arrays, resize, append

How to write a function, void append (int_array& iarr, int value), to add the given 'value' to the end of the array, and if size = capacity before append is called, the underlying array has to be resized to twice the capacity before appending the new element?

Notes: int_array is a struct with three elements:
int* array  (pointer to an underlying array)
int size, and 
int capacity

Comment: Please claify what programming language are you using. C++?

Comment: This feels like a homework question. Even if it is not, you should show what you have tried.

Comment: Yep, I'm using c++.